# cObject in Typolink assigned with border-content

Tags: lightbox, typo3, typoscript

Basically, I (think I ) need to know how to assign borderContent to a cObject, when it is a typolink parameter.

To tell the whole story: I'm using perfect lightbox, and I want it to open the lightbox when a text is clicked, and display the images that are in a single content element in the border section.

Looking through the manual, i found this code:

```
page.20 = TEXT
page.20.value = Open an image in a lightbox
page.20.typolink {
title = This is my caption
parameter.cObject = IMG_RESOURCE
parameter.cObject = fileadmin/image2.jpg
parameter.cObject.file.maxW = 600
parameter.cObject.file.maxH = 600
ATagParams = rel="lightbox[mySet]"
}
```

which is working fine. But I don't want the path to be hard set, but the content to be loaded from the border section, as I said. But if I try the following:

```
page.20 = TEXT
page.20.value = Open an image in a lightbox
page.20.typolink {
title = This is my caption
parameter.cObject = IMG_RESOURCE
parameter.cObject < styles.content.getBorder
parameter.cObject.file.maxW = 600
parameter.cObject.file.maxH = 600
ATagParams = rel="lightbox[mySet]"
}
```

the link is gone.

So I GUESS I'm assigning the content wrong. Somebody knows the answer?

Thanks!

(If of any help, I use automaketemplate..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning styles.content.getBorder will just assign the full content elements from the border column. This will not get you anywhere.

You will need to manually load the content elements from the border column, of course this can be done with TypoScript. It should be something like this:

```
page.20 = TEXT
page.20 {
    value = Open an image in a lightbox
    typolink {
        ATagParams = rel="lightbox[mySet]"
        title = This will be the title attribute
        parameter.cObject = CONTENT
        parameter.cObject {
            table = tt_content
            select {
                pidInList = this
                where = colPos = 3
            }

            renderObj = IMG_RESOURCE
            renderObj.file {
                import = uploads/pics
                import.field = image
                import.listNum = 0
                width = 600
                height = 600
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically this will load all content elements on the border position from the current page. Render the first image in the list of images and return you the resource.